# Getting html page in response during get token using admin credentials in magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, error, token, credentials

I tried to get an access token from Postman but received an HTML page in response. Here, the Magento base URL is https://www.qualityforms.com/. I don't know what settings need to be configured in the admin panel. Please guide me. I just want to get orders and item from magento using postman.

Comment: Can you please share the steps are followed & the HTML you are getting in the response?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the way to create the token via postman:**

**Select Postman Method:** POST

**Use URL like:**  https://your-domain.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token

**Use below content to the Body and type should be JSON:**

```
{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin@123"
}
```

**You can check the screenshot:**

[image]

**Note:** Please double verify the M2 admin user credentials used for the authentication

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried in the same way but encountered the same issue. I have identified the reason for it; the issue occurred because the provided credentials of the client were for Magento 1.9.

Comment: Okay so the issue was due to wrong credentials?